# Image file format not supported when downloaded from canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, download

When I download image versions of my canvas drawings I am unable to view or access them. My device keeps saying "doesn't support this file format" even though I have the image file labelled as "png" (lowercase too). The file downloads perfectly fine but that's about it. Any idea of what Im doing wrong?, below is the snippet of code. A link to my website too which is responsive [https://webdevcit.com/2018/Sem2/R00125891/Pages/structure/srctr1.html]

Any help would be very much appreciated

```
<a href="#" id='downloadLink' download="myDrawing.png">Download</a>

function createDownload() {
    const downloadURL = document.getElementById('c').toDataURL();
    document.getElementById('downloadLink').href = downloadURL;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open you downloaded file with a text editor and you will see it is a HTML Text file and not a PNG.

You are never calling the `createDownload()` function

Comment: Alright okay, what function would you recommend I use? Ive heard that the Blob function is popular with issues like

Comment: No I meant the issue is that you have the createDownload function but you are not using it. You need to call that function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!

```
let url = canvas.toDataURL();
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  a.download = "image.png";
  a.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Here at SO code only answers are **not considered good answers**, though, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. Answers with an explanation are always more helpful. The solution may be obvious to you. To others it may not. Please explain what it does, and how it's different from existing answers. Otherwise this answer may be flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality).